# Mongoose's findByIdAndUpdate not changing database's state

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a strange problem. I want to update a document in my MongoDB with the `mongoose.findByIdAndUpdate` method, but it seems not to be working. The code is:

```
Device.findByIdAndUpdate(
    req.params.id,
    { $set: { power: power } },
    { new: true },
    (err, device) => { ... }
```

I get no error, but the `device` returned in the callback does not have the updated value. At first I thought maybe it was some sort of problem with the `{ new: true }` option that tells mongoose to return the updated document, but then I checked the database, and the value there also has not been updated.

I also tried replacing `findByIdAndUpdate` with `update` function, but the results are the same - the db is not getting updated.

If it changes anything I use `mongoose.update()` function in other places and it works fine. I also tried the 'classical' way of updating the value here - meaning I used `findOne` function and then changed returned document's `power` field value and `save`d it and it also worked fine.

I will be really gratefull for any advice on fixing this. Thank you!

Comment: You can try turning on debug mode with `mongoose.set('debug', true);`. It might tell you something.

Comment: @MikaS I used debug and I get this: `Mongoose: devices.findOne({ _id: ObjectId("5a57b1c3451bec3ba73b7405") }, { new: true, fields: {} })`. The `ObjectId` field is ok, I set the `{ new: true }`, but I don't know how to interpret the empty `fields` field

Comment: fields will be empty until you deselect fields with the `.select()` function. So you don't have to worry about that. The `findOne` should be accompanied by an `update` right below it.

Comment: @MikaS everything I posted as the mongoose's response is what the debugger logged after calling `update`. So it was not really `findOne` but in fact `update`